# Есть ли аналоги паттерна nesteds sets?

Tags: php, mysql, nested-sets

Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли аналоги паттерна nesteds sets?

Comment: чем ассоциативный массив массивов не nested sets ?

Comment: Нужно хранить вложенность пользователей

Comment: пример пожалуйста.

я это так примерно вижу

    <?php
    
    $users=array();
    $users['user1']=array('name'=>'User 1');
    $users['user2']=array('name'=>'User 1','parent'=>&$users['user1']);
    print_r($users);

Comment: Это сколько же нужно массивов хранить что бы к примеру построить 20 000 структуру ?

Comment: один массив. вы как-то по другому себе это представляете ? обычно, в память весь граф не загоняют а только ветку нужную.

Comment: у первого юзера будет структура из всех, и тп. 

+ нужны такие моменты как например достать всю 4 линию конкретного пользователя. Я уже хранил массивы ранее, и постоянно нужно страдать фигней если честно в их пересчетах и тп. 

Сейчас открыл для себя materialized path, разбираюсь

Answer (score 2):

Существуют еще как минимум три паттерна, помимо вложенных множеств, для организации древовидных структур:

1. Список соседства (ключ `id` - родитель `parent_id`)
2. Перечисление путей (1/5/21/128/ - номера идентификаторы родителей)
3. Таблица замыканий или таблица связанности (Closure table), когда для организации отношений родитель-ребенок создается дополнительная таблица, где каждая запись соответствует одной связи.

Если у вас операции выборки сильно превышают операции вставки и редактирования, ничего лучше вложенных множеств в плане производительности нет. Если ситуация обратная, лучше рассмотреть таблицу замыканий - у него меньше всего подводных камней (особенно при редактировании).

Comment: Вот есть статья где это все расписано более детально: https://habr.com/post/46659/